# Como ler duas variáveis inteiras na mesma linha com PHP?

Tags: php, php-8

Gostaria de saber como eu posso atribuir valores, via console, a duas variáveis do tipo inteiro usando a mesma linha. Sei como fazer isso em Python e Java porém não sei em PHP.

Aqui está o código que estou testando.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

$numero1 = null;
$numero2 = null;

$numero1 = (int)readline("Informe o primeiro e o segundo número inteiro: ");
var_dump($numero1);
var_dump($numero2);
```

Comment: A pessoa vai separar por espaço, vírgula ou o que? Se puder [edit] e dar um exemplo do que é a entrada, ajuda. Tou tentando localizar outros posts que falam do assunto, mas basicamente é isso, você faz `$linha = readline('texto');` sem o int, vai vir uma stirng. Aí faz `$valores = explode('separador',$linha);`, ai os valores estarão em `$primeiro = (int) $valores[0]`, `$segundo = (int) $valores[1]` ... etc

Answer (score 0):

É só usar o código abaixo, no explode você pode mudar o 'separador', no exemplo é uma vírgula mas poderia ser um espaço por exemplo: `explode(' ',$numero);`

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
$numero = null;
$numero1 = null;
$numero2 = null;

$numero = readline("Informe o primeiro e o segundo número inteiro: "); // ex: 1,2
$numero = explode(',',$numero);

$numero1 = (int)$numero[0];
$numero2 = (int)$numero[1];

var_dump($numero1);
var_dump($numero2);
```

Comment: Use formatos, referências, como o da própria função [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php) do [tag:php]. Veja [como escrever uma boa resposta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

É possível extrair de uma string de entrada um array de strings compostas apenas números inteiros independente de ser especificado algum separador.
Para isso basta dividir a string entrada a cada caractere que não seja um dígito decimal com [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match-all.php).

A função `preg_match_all()` captura as correspondências de um padrão [expressão regular](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) numa string.
Pode-se instruir a `preg_match_all()` que capture apenas os números inteiros da string com o padrão 
`/[-+]?\d+/`.
A flag `PREG_SET_ORDER` ordena os resultados de forma que que o primeiro valor da matriz de captura seja primeiro conjunto de correspondências, o segundo valor da matriz de captura seja seja o conjunto de correspondências e assim por diante.

Com a função [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php) aplique a função de conversão para inteiros [`intval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.intval.php) a cada elemento da array anteriormente retornado por `preg_match_all()` achatado pela função [`array_merge()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-merge.php) .

Com [`list()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) faça a atribuição de um array para múltiplas variáveis.

```php
<?php

$entrada = readline("Informe o primeiro e o segundo número inteiro: "); 

preg_match_all('/[-+]?\d+/', $entrada, $numeros, PREG_SET_ORDER);

list($numero1, $numero2) = array_map('intval', array_merge(...$numeros));


var_dump($numero1);
var_dump($numero2);
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/N1N2#main.php)</sup>

Comment: Por qual motivo adicionou o "pipe" dentro do `[-|+]`?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento corrigido